# How to convert mouseover and mouseout events to touch events in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mouseover, touch-event, mouseout

I have an application that creates a *trailing-lights* effect when you hover over colorless squares defined inside a container. When a **mouseover** event occurs, the squares are filled with a **random color** and when a **mouseout** event occurs the **color fades away** into its previous state. And this only works on desktops.

Here is a working demo https://therealrajan.github.io/HoverBoard/ and here is the GitHub repo I'm working with https://github.com/TheRealRajan/HoverBoard

This is all the code.

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const colors = ['#3891a6', '#fde74c', '#ec9e57', '#e4795c', '#db5461','#e3655b','#95b8d1', '#666a86', '#edafb8', '#f42272', '#2541b2', '#1768ac', '#06bee1','#003459', '#662c91', '#17a398']

const SQUARES = 621

for(let i =0; i < SQUARES ; i++){
    const square = document.createElement('div')
    square.classList.add('square')

    square.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=> setColor(square))
    square.addEventListener('mouseout', ()=> removeColor(square))

    container.appendChild(square)
}

function setColor(element){
    const color = getRandomColor()
    element.style.background = color
    element.style.boxShadow = `0 0 5px ${color}`
}

function removeColor(element){
    element.style.background = '#1d1d1d'
    element.style.boxShadow = '0 0 2px #000'
}

function getRandomColor(){
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
}
```

**I couldn't figure out how to convert it so it works with touch inputs. How do I change it so that it also works with touch events on devices with touchscreens?**

> ```
> square.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=> setColor(square))
> square.addEventListener('mouseout', ()=> removeColor(square))
> ```

Comment: i think that [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_touchevent.asp) gonna work

Comment: You're gonna have to use [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent). I'm not sure if `touchstart` will fire when you drag your touching finger into an element, though.

Comment: I tried using touchstart but the function only fires once when you touch your finger on the screen and only one square lights up. It actually works like a mouse click event. 
I think what would work is touchmove so that the function keeps firing until the event is active but that doesnt work on its own either. I think touchstart has to be trigerred first before touchmove. I tried different combinations of touch events but it didnt seem  to work.